# how to raise interface from application class?

Tags: android, interface

friends,

i am running async task from application onCreate()

now i want to raise an interface on completion of this task and implement it in ACtivity B.

any one guide me how to achieve this?

my Interface

```
public interface IBanksLoader 
{
    public void OnBankLoadingComplete(boolean complete);
}
```

in application class

```
AsyncTask
{

any other function();
// to raise it here
}


Activity b
{

// implement it here to get result.
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "raise an interface"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) to implement this behavior.

Activity B would implement the IBanksLoader (observer) interface and register itself to some central component. This central component must get notified when the AsyncTask finished and calls then OnBankLoadingComplete() (is equivalent to notify() of the Observer interface) of all registered observers.

I would suggest to use a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) or an [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class as central component as they can be accessed easily form anywhere within your application, also from the AsyncTask.

But be aware of your application's life cycle. So your might need to unregister Activity B at some time, e.g. before it gets destroyed. Otherwise the central component would call OnBankLoadingComplete() on an object which is null and thus raise a NullPointerException.

UPDATE

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity implements IBanksLoader {

    public void onCreate(){           
        ...

        MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplication();
        app.register(this);

        ...
    }

    public void OnBankLoadingComplete(boolean complete){

         // your code here ...
    }

    public void onDestroy(){
        MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplication();
        app.unregister(this);
    }
}


public class MyApplication extends Application{

    private List<IBanksLoader> observers = new ArrayList<IBanksLoader>();

    public void register(IBanksLoader observer){
        if(observer != null){
            oberservers.add(observer);
        }
    }

    public void unregister(IBanksLoader observer){
        if(observer != null){
            oberservers.remove(observer);
        }
    }

    public void taskfinished(){
        foreach(IBanksLoader bank : observers){
            if(bank != null){
                bank.OnBankLoadingComplete(true);
            }
        }
    }
}


public class MyTask extends AsyncTask{
    ... 

    public void onPostExecute(){
        MyApplication app = (MyApplication) getApplication();
        app.taskfinished();
    }
    ...    
}
```

Comment: could you please provide any sample code? or short idea pseudo code like thing its quite tough to understand for me.